# Build Errors When Migrating to VS 2010 and .NET4.0 from VS 2008 and .NET3.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, build, .net-4.0, compiler-errors

I have a VS 2008 project. This project's target framework 3.5. Everything is Ok in this situation.

I migrated this project to VS 2010 and I also changed target framework to .Net 4.0. Then I tried to build the project. But I got an error which says me to about to use "NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy" switch. So I used that switch and errors related to this switch got away. But this time I encountered a different error which says "The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly. System.InvalidOperationException: The security state of an AppDomain was modified by an AppDomainManager configured with the NoSecurityChanges flag.....". I searched this on web but I could not find a solution. Does anybody experiences this problem. Thanks for your help?

Comment: Does it error on any specific line in your source, or does it simply not like a configuration option in your project?

Comment: Hi Nate, it does not error on any specific line in source.

Answer (score 0):

On your build server locate msbuild.exe.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 (you'll also have to change the x64 version if you're on a 64-bit box).

Add the following to the bottom of the config (in the  section)

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

In other words the end of your config should look like:

```
        </assemblyBinding>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
    <!-- To define one or more new toolsets, add an 'msbuildToolsets' element in this file. -->
</configuration>
```